Python cryptography reading from encrypted SQLite table
I'm a bit new with encryption however I have a class which encrypts a data frame and writes to a SQLite file. Then the inverse a class to decrypt the same SQLite table
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
import getpass
import sys
        
class Data_Encryptor_SQLite:
    def __init__(self, db_name, df, table_name):
        self.db_name = db_name
        self.df = df
        self.table_name = table_name
        self.password = getpass.getpass(prompt = "Enter password to lock: ").encode()
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
        self.salt = None

        # Ensure password is provided
        if not self.password:
            raise ValueError("Password is required.")
        
        self.get_salt()
        # Generate key and Cipher from password 
        self.hash_password()
        # Create table and encrypt data
        self.create_table()
        self.encrypt_and_store_dataframe()
    
    def get_salt(self):
        with open('locationof.key_file', 'rb') as file:
            self.salt = file.read()
        
        
    def encrypt_data(self, data):
        #Cipher Encryption from fernet key(data encoded into bytes) then decoded into a string to store in SQL 
        return self.cipher.encrypt(data.encode()).decode()

    def hash_password(self):

        def kdf():
            return PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), 
                              length=32, 
                              salt=self.salt, 
                              iterations=100000)

        
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf().derive(self.password))
                 
        self.cipher = Fernet(key)
          

    def create_table(self):
        columns_def = ', '.join([f"{col} TEXT" for col in self.df.columns])
        create_table_sql = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {self.table_name} ({columns_def})"
        self.conn.execute(create_table_sql)
        self.conn.commit()

    def encrypt_and_store_dataframe(self):
        for _, row in self.df.iterrows():
            # encrypted_row = [self.encryptor.encrypt_data(str(val)) for val in row]
            encrypted_row = [self.encrypt_data(str(val)) for val in row]
            insert_sql = f"INSERT INTO {self.table_name} VALUES ({','.join(['?' for _ in range(len(row))])})"
            self.conn.execute(insert_sql, encrypted_row)
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()
        
        print('encrypted table complete')


class Data_Decryptor_SQLite:
    def __init__(self, db_name, table_name):
        self.db_name = db_name
        self.table_name = table_name
        self.password = getpass.getpass(prompt = "Enter password to lock: ").encode()
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
        self.salt = None
        self.df = None

        # Ensure password is provided
        if not self.password:
            raise ValueError("Password is required.")
        
        self.get_salt()
        # Generate key and Cipher from password 
        self.hash_password()

        #Run over SQl table and return df decrypted 
        self.fetch_and_decrypt_dataframe()
        
            
    def get_salt(self):
        with open('locationof.key_file', 'rb') as file:
            self.salt = file.read()
        
        
    def decrypt_data(self, data):
        #Cipher Encryption from fernet key(data encoded into bytes) then decoded into a string to store in SQL 
        return self.cipher.decrypt(data.encode()).decode()

    def hash_password(self):

        def kdf():
            return PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), 
                              length=32, 
                              salt=self.salt, 
                              iterations=100000)

        
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf().derive(self.password))
        
        self.cipher = Fernet(key)
          
    
    def fetch_and_decrypt_dataframe(self):
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {self.table_name}")
        encrypted_data = cursor.fetchall()
        decrypted_data = []
        for row in encrypted_data:
            # decrypted_row = [self.encryptor.decrypt_data(encrypted_val) for encrypted_val in row]
            decrypted_row = [self.decrypt_data(encrypted_val) for encrypted_val in row]
            decrypted_data.append(decrypted_row)
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(decrypted_data, columns=[d[0] for d in cursor.description])
        self.conn.close()

Encryption works perfectly, I've copied the code to the decryption class however I'm faced with the same error cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken

You can use print(repr(...)) or a debugger to check what is written to the database and what is read from the database

Pardon my ignorance regarding SQL in general and sqlite in particular, but aren't you just inserting encrypted rows into the table rather than replacing the plaintext row with the encrypted row?

thanks for the query @PresidentJamesK.Polk SQLite I don't think cant hold encrypted data so its converted to plain text. A longer process. The decryption is the issue onces its coming back from SQLite

Solution below:
`
class Data_Encryptor_SQLite:
    def __init__(self, db_name, df, table_name):
        self.db_name = db_name
        self.df = df
        self.table_name = table_name
        self.password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter password to lock: ").encode()
        self.salt = None

        # Ensure password is provided
        if not self.password:
            raise ValueError("Password is required.")

        self.get_salt()
        # Generate key and Cipher from password
        self.hash_password()
        # Create table and encrypt data
        self.create_table()
        self.encrypt_and_store_dataframe()

    def get_salt(self):
        with open('locationof.key_file', 'rb') as file:
            self.salt = file.read()

    def encrypt_data(self, data):
        return self.cipher.encrypt(data.encode()).decode()

    def hash_password(self):
        kdf = self.get_kdf()
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(self.password))
        self.cipher = Fernet(key)

    def get_kdf(self):
        return PBKDF2HMAC(
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            length=32,
            salt=self.salt,
            iterations=100000,
        )

    def create_table(self):
        columns_def = ', '.join([f"{col} TEXT" for col in self.df.columns])
        create_table_sql = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {self.table_name} ({columns_def})"
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_name)
        self.conn.execute(create_table_sql)
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

    def encrypt_and_store_dataframe(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_name)
        for _, row in self.df.iterrows():
            encrypted_row = [self.encrypt_data(str(val)) for val in row]
            insert_sql = f"INSERT INTO {self.table_name} VALUES ({','.join(['?' for _ in range(len(row))])})"
            self.conn.execute(insert_sql, encrypted_row)
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()
        print('Encrypted table complete')


class Data_Decryptor_SQLite:
    def __init__(self, db_name, table_name):
        self.db_name = db_name
        self.table_name = table_name
        self.password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter password to lock: ").encode()
        self.salt = None
        self.df = None

        # Ensure password is provided
        if not self.password:
            raise ValueError("Password is required.")

        self.get_salt()
        # Generate key and Cipher from password
        self.hash_password()

        # Run over SQL table and return decrypted DataFrame
        self.fetch_and_decrypt_dataframe()

    def get_salt(self):
        with open('locationof.key_file', 'rb') as file:
            self.salt = file.read()

    def decrypt_data(self, data):
        return self.cipher.decrypt(data.encode()).decode()

    def hash_password(self):
        kdf = self.get_kdf()
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(self.password))
        self.cipher = Fernet(key)

    def get_kdf(self):
        return PBKDF2HMAC(
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            length=32,
            salt=self.salt,
            iterations=100000,
        )

    def fetch_and_decrypt_dataframe(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_name)
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {self.table_name}")
        encrypted_data = cursor.fetchall()
        decrypted_data = []
        for row in encrypted_data:
            decrypted_row = [self.decrypt_data(encrypted_val) for encrypted_val in row]
            decrypted_data.append(decrypted_row)
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(decrypted_data, columns=[d[0] for d in cursor.description])
        self.conn.close()

# Example usage
# encryptor = Data_Encryptor_SQLite('example.db', df, 'encrypted_table')
# decryptor = Data_Decryptor_SQLite('example.db', 'encrypted_table')

`
